# ThinkPad T480's touchpad receives intermittent random input after a few minutes of use

Tags: drivers, touchpad, 19.10, thinkpad, synaptics

I'm having a strange intermittent problem with my nearly brand new ThinkPad T480's touchpad upon a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10 (Linux 5.3.0).

After using the touchpad for a few minutes after boot the cursor will start flailing about the screen wildly. While running the `evhz` command I can see that the touchpad is receiving constant random input making it nearly impossible to control for the period of time when it happens. After a couple seconds the touchpad will return to normal and be usable again, though another several seconds later it returns to its panicked state, and continues to thrash around completely out of my control.

The only fix for it is to 1: reboot the machine, or 2: `rmmod && insmod` the `psmouse` module (or any other module required to control the touchpad), although these solutions are only temporary as the problem reemerges soon after.

Out of curiosity, I decided to load up Windows 10 to see if the problem persisted even on a wholly different operating system. On Windows the problem completely went away and the laptop worked perfectly (aside from running windows).

Intermittent problems like these are usually hardware related, but I suspect that this one is not.

Is this a known issue? If so, is there a fix? It's becoming very difficult to use my laptop so I would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please can you show `lsusb`

Comment: I have a T480s running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, this is my `lsbusb` output: `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc.` -- I don't have this issue but I thought it might help if anyone needs info.